# Datetimepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a situation with datetimepicker. It doesn't show any calendar When I click the icon.

The chrome browser not showing any errors in the development console.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script> 
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row cuadrado">   
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-1"><h4>Fecha de Nacimiento :</h4></div>        
       <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-1">               
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type='text' id="fecha_nac" runat="server" name="fecha_nac" class="form-control input_margin" readonly="true" placeholder="Eliga la fecha"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>      
       </div>  
   </div>

 $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1>input').datetimepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
        });   
        });
```

Comment: There are some signs missing like: }) (curly-braces and bracket). Or did you not pass all code into your answer?

Comment: Bootstrap-datetimepicker Doc refers to this list of valid formats: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ You may have to write: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: format: "YYYY-MM-DD" and  "DD/MM/YYYY"  doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier if you provide the input with a proper `id` and bind the `datetimepicker` plugin to it.

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <div class="input-group">
            <input name="date" type="text" id="my-date" class="form-control form-date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$( '#my-date' ).datetimepicker( { format: 'MM-DD-YYYY' } );
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/go6ygh6q/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all just include the `jquery ui.min.js` file for example

```
<link href="Contents" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-2.1.1.min.js">
```

and then write the code accordingly as mentioned below:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd,MM,yy",
  showOn: "button",
  buttonText: "Select Date",
  changeYear: "true",
  changeMonth:"true"
});
```

Comment: The question is about bootstrap datepicker, not jquery ui datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

add class="form-group",this works for me, but I don't know why

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type='text' id="fecha_nac" runat="server" name="fecha_nac" class="form-control input_margin" readonly="true" placeholder="Eliga la fecha"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
     </div>    
</div>
```